# Display child pages in Wordpress home page with thumbnail, title and page limit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to display child pages with **thumbnail, title and page limit** to my Wordpress home page, but I didn't know how to code. Pleas help me to solve it.

```
<?php
$ancestor_id=29;
$nbpages = 2;
$pagesd = wp_list_pages(array(
"child_of" => $ancestor_id,
"include" => $incl,
"link_before" => "",
"title_li" => "",
"sort_column" =>
"menu_order"));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with this. Should work to :
1. Retrieve all the pages with the parent $ancestor_id
2. Loops through the results and echoes the page title and the thumbnail.

```
 $ancestor_id = 29;
 $pg_args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => $ancestor_id,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$pages = get_pages($pg_args);

    foreach($pages as $page){
        echo $page->post_title;
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page);
    }
```